# Update where comparing dates from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I've got two tables one with values and the other with users.

I want to update my `Table_1.value` to `a` where my `Table_1.date < user_table.date` for a given `user_id`.

```
Table_1

|user_id | value | date       |
|--------|-------|------------|
|   1    |   f   | 2013-12-11 |
|--------|-------|------------|
|   2    |   k   | 2013-12-05 |
|--------|-------|------------|
|   3    |   l   | 2013-12-01 |
|--------|-------|------------|
|   4    |   n   | 2013-11-09 |
|--------|-------|------------|
|   4    |   a   | 2012-10-11 |
|--------|-------|------------|
|   2    |   v   | 2013-11-07 |
|--------|-------|------------|
|   1    |   o   | 2013-12-10 |
|--------|-------|------------|
|   3    |   p   | 2013-11-15 |

user_table

|user_id | date       |
|--------|------------|
|   1    | 2013-12-15 |
|--------|------------|
|   2    | 2013-11-03 |
|--------|------------|
|   3    | 2013-12-11 |
|--------|------------|
|   4    | 2013-12-09 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
update table1 inner join user_table
              on (table1.user_id = user_table.user_id 
                  and table1.date < user_table.date)
  set table1.value = 'a'
```

If you want to add a specific user add `where table1.user_id = 1` or any id.

See it on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0895/1

**Edit**

As the requirements change (one more table), it will be:

```
UPDATE table_1 inner join table_3 
                on (table_1.date = table_3.date) 
      inner join user_table on 
       (table1.user_id = user_table.user_id 
          and table1.date < user_table.date ) 
    set table_1.value = table_3.value
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to `SET` the value from a `Table_3` for then it throw me `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column Table_1.user_id in on clause`. I did `UPDATE table_1, table_3 inner join user_table
              on (table1.user_id = user_table.user_id 
                  and table1.date < user_table.date) set table_1.value = table_3.value where table_1.date = table_3.date`

Comment: Edited my answer. see if it fits.

Comment: Your answer was right, I just needed to put Table_3 after the end of the inner join. Thanks

Comment: Well. I put on my answer the right way to do the update that you show on the comments, it also should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
update Table_1,user_table
set value='a'
where Table_1.user_id = user_table.user_id
  and Table_1.date < user_table.date
```